# How can I split a file based on a line in PHP?

Tags: php, file-io, subset, fread

I have a file named doremi.txt, which goes as follows

```
These are the notes 
I sing
They fly and dance 
like a bird's wing
--------------------
Do
Re
Mi
Fa
So
La
Ti
TaDa!
```

I want to read through the text file using this, but I only want the information that is after the dashed line (the musical notes):

```
// filename in this case is DoReMi.txt

        $file = fopen ( $filename, 'r' );
        $fileContents = nl2br ( fread ( $file, filesize( $filename )));

        $lines = 0;
        while(!feof($file)){
            $curr = fgets($file, 999);
            $lines++;
            // this should count the number of lines in the text file
        }

        echo "--------------------";
        // This is my problem area
        // I want to "ignore" the information before this line


        fclose( $file );
        echo "# of notes: $lines";
        echo "<hr/> $fileContents <hr/>";
```

Since this is a file and not a string or a list, I know that I cannot create a substring or new array.

In addition, fgetscsv wouldn't work because it is a single line rather than each line in the file.

Comment: Look at `$curr` and after dashes match start capturing the content.

Comment: If it's simply a "split in two by --------", then you can `file_get_contents` to get the whole file, and `explode` or `preg_split` by dash, then use the second half of the resulting array. Or something like this: https://3v4l.org/5oujo ... `list($words, $notes) = preg_split('~\s*--------------------\s*~', $str);`.

Comment: How can I start capturing the content if I am reading the file?